# How to make a website mint multiple copies of the same NFT?

Tags: nft

On OpenSea, I know how to make multiple copies of the same NFT (you just make the set number larger). However I don’t want to use OpenSea, because I want a minting website, where users can mint their own. How do I set up a minting website with multiple of the same NFT (as in a set)?

Thanks!